# General element of the Poincare group

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, topology, poincare-symmetry

Consider the generators of the Poincare group are $M^{\mu\nu}$ and $P^\mu$. The Lorentz group elements are $g(\omega)\in SO(1,3)=e^{-\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\nu}}$ and the translation group elements are $g(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{1,3}=e^{ix_\mu P^\mu}$. We represent the Poincare group element as $g(\omega,x)\in ISO(1,3)=e^{-\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\nu}+ix_\mu P^\mu}$. This is fine from infinitesimal transformation level.

Now when we represent Minkowski space, we write $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}=\frac{ISO(1,3)}{SO(1,3)}$. This is what Hopf fibration is. But I can not visualize this. Since $M^{\mu\nu}$ and $P^\mu$ do not commute, we can not write the $ISO(1,3)$ group element as just multiplication of Lorentz and translation group, or $g(\omega,x)\neq g(\omega)g(x)$ (due to BCH lemma). So, how this fibration makes sense?